# How to set double quoted value in select box using jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to show the previously selected value from the database to the select option using jquery.

my value is 40"X48".
the code i used

```
    <?php $pallets_type = 40"X48"; ?>
    var pallets_type = "<?=htmlentities($pallets_type);?>";
    $('select[name=pallets_type]').val(pallets_type);
```

but it's not working for me.

Comment: `$pallets_type = 40"X48";` is not right. You forgot `php` tags and `'` around your string: `<?php $pallets_type = '40"X48"'; ?>`

Comment: i have added in the actual code but forgot to mention here.

Comment: Still missing quotes around your string.

Comment: I think you have this issue because `htmlentities()` will transform `"` to `&quot;` and that your `<option>` values have `40"x48"`, not `40&quot;x48&quot;`.

Answer (score 0):

Add double quotation marks in single quote sign like:

```
$pallets_type = '40"X48"'; 
var pallets_type = "<?=htmlentities($pallets_type);?>";
$('select[name=pallets_type]').append('<option>"'+pallets_type+'"</option>');
```